# Backup of mysql DB not being created

Tags: mysql

i want to write mysql DB on CD. I've followed the steps of creating backup. i've created server instance in server administration. now when i double click it to open it, it gives an error "Error starting Workbench Administrator; `Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled`".

i went to administrative tools. enabled wmi for all users in Root Security. but its still giving the same error. What to do?

Comment: What steps did you follow ?

Answer (score 2):

This error `Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled` is occurred due to newly created server is not updated in `server instances`.

If you got below error when click on `Manage Import / Export` option

[image: manageserverinstances 0]

Follow the steps

**Step 1:** Click on `Manage Server Instaces`

[image: manageserverinstances 1]

**Step 2:** Click on Manage Connections button, `Manage DB Connections` window will be opens.

[image: manageserverinstances 2]

**Step 3:** Select `instance` and click on `Store in Vault` button, `Store Password For 
Connection` window will be opens.

[image: manageserverinstances 3]

**Step 4:** Enter `Password` then click on `OK` button.

[image: manageserverinstances 4]

**Step 5:** Click on `Test Connection` button for check database is connected with mysql or not, `Connected to Mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root` window will be opens.

[image: manageserverinstances 5]

**Step 6:** Click on `OK` button then `Close button`.

**Step 7:** Click on `Close` button to close `Manage Server Instances` window.

[image: manageserverinstances 6]

**Step 8:** Click on `Manage Import / Export`.

[image: manageserverinstances 7]

Step 9: Finally Import and Export browser will be opens.

[image: manageserverinstances 8]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the WMI exception you mention trying to make a new server instance under the "Server Administration" of mysql's "Workbench Central". I had been trying "Take Parameters from Existing Database Connection" and choosing my local DB when I got the exception.

In that first "Specify the Host Machine the Database Server is running on" screen, I needed to choose the first option, "localhost".

[image]

This let me create a connection to my local server through which I could import data that I had exported from another database. The export was made into a flat .sql file.

You might try simply exporting to a .sql file and then putting that file on a CD.