# MySQL Workbench acquire access for administration?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I run MySQL 5.6 since month and everything went well. Also the MySQL Workbench 6.

I receive two errors if I would like to see the "Server Status".

1st error:

```
Could not acquire management access for admionistration
RuntimeError: Unable to execute comand chcp. Please make shure that
C:\Windows\System32 directory is in your PATH environment variable.
```

I checked the windows path variable within Win7 and there exist an entry c:\windows\system32

2nd error:

```
Unable exception: Current profile has no WMI enable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

To resolve the issue, simply click on **Manage Server Instances** under **Server Administration** column and close the screen again.
Now click on the instance again, check if the issue is fixed or report any bug.

Comment: Solved, software things ;-)

Comment: I see this is a few months old, still...  I couldn't find that option in the Ubuntu version of Workbench.  Would anyone know the equivalent command?  Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone confirm is this option is there in workbench version **6.3.6** and later?  I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: I am getting this error on v8.0.22 and I can't find `Manage Server Instances under Server Administration`

Answer (score 8):

I thought your MYSQl Service is not yet start. 
Please Follow the below steps It works me like a charm.
windows + R - Type **services.msc** Press 'Enter' you could see many services . There is a service called **MYSQl56 service** if it's **Disabled** please Start that Service then once again restart the workbench.

Comment: i have problem while starting this service . dialogue box appears and it says mysql57 on local computer started and then stoped

Comment: There is no "MYSQl56 service".

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still facing issue, add "C:\Windows\System32" in "path" Environmental Variable and make sure "MySQL56" service is running.

Answer (score 1):

I follow those steps:

1. I started MySQL80 in Services.
2. Changed Server -> Management Access Settings -> System Profile, from Windows to Linux so then I entered into Server Status and refreshed.

I hope that can to help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

If you got below error when click on `Manage Import / Export` option

[image: manageserverinstances 0]

Previously asked question `Backup of mysql DB not being created` is answered [Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21988037/1624035)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to install my first mySQL server.

When configuring Remote Management, I overlooked the operating system setting for my server.  I was using Windows but the default was set to FreeBSD.  Once I changed the server OS setting to Windows, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered exactly the same problem - read lots of suggestions but solutions didn't work for me (I can't un-install MySQL and re-install it on a live server)...
...my resolution, and what worked for me, was to copy chcp.com from C:\Windows\System32\ to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
I guess it's a path problem between a 32bit version of MySQL/Workbench and the 64bit OS

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after restarting my pc and solved it by just starting wampserver!
so the solution is: 
1. start wampserver- make sure apache,mysql are running and put all services online.
2.try to reconnect to the database!

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, mine didn't work after the solution given by @mohit, and I'd rather not restart the computer as a work around as some has suggested.

After doing some digging around, I found that the mysql server service was not running

`Task Manager --> Services --> [mysqlxx]`   right click and click start if not running. Note that. Note that `[mysqlxx]` could be a different format or name where `xx` are numbers

Answer (score 0):

i solved it installing the latest version of MySQL Workbench and server then I changed the line `process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)` on C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\os_utils to `process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding="ansi", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)` 
Looks like working :D