# MySQL 6.3 Workbench Connectivity Issues

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-connect

I'm long been away from MySQL I'm having connectivity issues in establishing connection with my localhost I also added System32 folder to my PATH variable. What could I be missing?

Comment: A detailed description of the issues you are experiencing, like exact error messages and/or behavior of the tool?

Comment: @fvu Here's the link to error screen that pops up: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByiH20BOXImtbHh0ZlRnWGlLTTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266440/mysql-workbench-acquire-access-for-administration ?  There are two things you could test there.