# MySQL Workbench 6.0 error could not acquire managemant access for the administrator?

Tags: java, mysql, .net, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.0 over here. When I select the server status, I am getting this error

[image]

Regarding this, I tried looking for solutions on Google and StackOverflow (*e.g. [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462706/backup-of-mysql-db-not-being-created/21988037#21988037)*)

But here in MySQL Workbench 6.0, I don't know where is `Server Administration` of Mysql's and `Workbench Central`.

Can anyone help me regarding this issue in MySQL Workbench 6.0?

Comment: I've reproduced the same issue using MySQL Server 8.0.23 & MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 for 64-bit OS Windows 10 and added answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65839054/8370915) for newer versions.

Answer (score 4):

Try running `chcp` in a terminal window (command line window). Does it run there? It should print out the current code page. Ensure the `chcp` command can be found by having the system path in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and i tried so many thing to work, the only thing that works for me was check the Environment Variables, for this do:

- Right click on My Computer>Properties
- Advanced system settings
- Environment Variables
- In the field "Environment Variables" search for Path

  Search for %SystemRoot%; and %SystemRoot%\system32; if you don't see them there, add it on the final of the line (please don't delete the other things there!).

  - That's it.

Answer (score 0):

On 64 bits system you need copy chcp.com from system32 to SysWOW64

Answer (score 0):

For me solve was to enable MYSQL80 service (for some reason it was disabled):
Tasks manager -> Services -> Open services -> find MYSQL80 -> start it