# Could not acquire management access for administration. Runtime Error: Unable to excute command chcp

Tags: runtime-error, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL workbench 8.0 in windows 7. After the installation I just clicked server status its through the error like `Could not acquire management access for administration. Run-time Error: Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:Windows\System32 directory is in your path environment variable`. How can I solve this error?

Comment: why tagged ms-access?

Answer (score 22):

I solved the same problem on enable the parameter "Beta : Use UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Change system locale...
It's disturbing because it's have nothing about the PATH environment variable. But it's work.
Notice that I working on french environment and MySQL Workbench 8.0.24 version.

Comment: OK for me : Panneau de configuration > Horloge et région > Région > Onglet Administration > Modifier les paramètres régionaux > Cocher Bêta : "Utiliser le format UTF-8 etc."

Comment: Does the use of the beta version of Unicode support bring any drawbacks?

Answer (score 6):

I've reproduced the same issue by clicking *server status*:

```
Could not acquire management access for administration

RuntimeError: Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:\Windows\System32 directory is in your PATH environment variable
```

and after click `cancel` was:

```
Error during ""

error calling Python module function WbAdmin.openAdminSection
```

using **MySQL Server 8.0.23 & MySQL Workbench 8.0.23** for 64-bit OS **Windows 10**.

**Notice:** [all environment variables were configured correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273868/8370915) in my case.

Solved it only by reinstalling and using another version like **MySQL Workbench 8.0.20**, but I'd really recommend also downgrade version of server to **MySQL Server 8.0.20** to avoid other bugs, e.g.: creating/deleting schemes and so on.

**The same version should match all products to work correctly.**

Comment: Just to let others know, I tried all other solutions (from this question and also from other questions). Downgrading from 8.0.23 to either 8.0.22 / 8.0.21 / 8.0.20 was the only working solution for me on my Windows 10 64-bits (all three versions 22/21/20 worked just fine, without the bug).

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this problem on 64 bit system we have to follow two steps.

1. add environment variable path to `C:\Windows\System32`
2. we need chcp.com cmd file in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` 
       copy it from `C:\Windows\System32 path and paste in C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

   now close `mysql` workbench and reopen it.

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: “C:\Windows\SysWOW64” has its own “chcp.com” file with different size. I doubt that replacing it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution for system non english language users! After failing in all attempts seen issue here: [Mysql Bug Forum](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102300), where told that the problem is in unicode python codec error. So mine solution as for cyrillic language user was to set Windows administrative language for the cases when utf-8 is unavailable, see screenshot below.
["System language old value was Russian, after changing to English (USA) everything started to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKc8.png)
Also watched Workbench logs - there was a python exception for the ascii codec. Thats all, hope this will help.

Comment: Attention! Use this carefull, mine Intellij IDEA started to work uncorrect after this system setup - was uninformative "ClassNotFound exceptions" on every code that worked well. Only after returning everything as it was before helped. So at this moment i have OR working properly MySQL Workbench OR IDEA at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before there are 2 possible fixes:

1. Change system locale to English(US)
2. Use Workbench ver. 8.0.22 or lower (error appears on vers. 8.0.23+)

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'C:\Windows\System32' to the PATH environment variable.

**Make sure you add it to PATH and not to Path.**

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem for me was this:
Start the workbench community installer after installing the program you will go to this window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPMhR.png) then you start the option of MySQL Server the option of "Reconfigure" and you accept all the options and create a new password (if you didn't make it before), execute the final screen and you are ready to use workbench :D

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error for Windows 10. For me solution was to reinstall *MySQL Server 8.0.24* and to enable option in installer "*Configure MySQL Server as a Windows Service*". Didn't have this option marked in the first installation, so I assume the problem was in this(there were no service for it, so after system restart MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE gave an error).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise **AGAINST** installing MySQL on your local Windows machine. It isn't suitable for this and may lead to such unpleasant issues.

The better option would be to create a Linux Ubuntu virtual machine in Hyper-V and connect your app to it.

Hopefully, this hint will lead you further.

**NOTE:** You need to have a Windows PRO version. If you are working on Windows Home, there is no such option.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `C:\Windows\System32` to the Path, and the problem will be solved!

Don't forget to add `";"` to separate addresses.