# Mysql server: i got connected to localhost, and after that when i click server startup/shutdown i am getting error message

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[I am getting error message when I click server startup/shutdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2iWu.png)

Comment: Read the error message. Fix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the problem, change the system locale to English. To change the
system locale:

- Open language settings
- Click "Administrative language settings" at the right top of the Window
- Click "Change system locale"
- Select English (United States) for example
- Click OK
- Restart the system


  The workaround above is not affordable, nor acceptable in many cases for compatibility reasons. Even if WB runs well, other application may face charset problems.

  If you get the same error after doing this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236494/could-not-acquire-management-access-for-administration-runtime-error-unable-to).