# I get this message in MYSQL in Windows: Target host is configured as Windows, but seems to be a different OS. Please review the connection settings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set a MySQL Database in my pc for development.

[image: error Message]

Of course I've tried to change the OS

[image: OS configuration]

None of this options made it work.

Although when I hit the testconnection button it shows success, the OS message error keeps being shown and I cannot use my database.

[image: Connection Success]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236494/could-not-acquire-management-access-for-administration-runtime-error-unable-to

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the control panel, then region, then clic in the administrative tab and click on "change system regional settings" and as a final step check the box: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support, restart your PC and try to access MySQL Workbench.

[image: Check this box]

Answer (score 1):

Although the option proposed by Fernando Valderrama Guayán is functional I would not recommend activating a beta version option, since depending on your configuration strange symbols could appear in the rest of the operating system.

The solution with less collateral effects would be to edit the file 'os_utils.py' in the path 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench'.

We look for the line:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

And we replace it with:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding='ansi', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).
```

The idea is to modify the encoding parameter to the **ansi** encoding system.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in MySQL Workbench **8.0.28**
Using MySQL Installer, you can uninstall the workbench then install the MySQL Workbench **8.0.16**.
It will work well.