# MySQL Workbench: "Runtime error: Unable to execute command chcp"

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I had a working app that used MySQL. Then, for memory reasons, I uninstalled Workbench (and everything that I believed related to MySQL), installed it again some months later, and opened it. I didn't expect to see the connections I had back then (I thought I uninstalled and deleted everything), but they were there. When I double-click any of those connections now, including the root connection, I get an error message that says

> Could not acquire management access for administration
>
> Runtime error: Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:\Windows\System32 directory is in your PATH environment variable

I don't understand this whole "PATH variable" concept, but it seems I have that line

When I click this

[image]

I get this

[image]

I tried adding `C:\Windows\System32` to that list again, but it didn't help, I get the same error message

When I close the original error message, a new one pops up

> Unhandled Exception: Current Profile has no WMI enabled
>
> Check the log for more details

I checked the log, but I don't find it very helpful. If you don't mind, I'll copy it in its entirety

```
17:57:22 [ERR][      Workbench]: Console redirection failed.
17:57:22 [INF][      Workbench]: Starting up Workbench
17:57:22 [INF][      Workbench]: Current environment:
    Command line: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe"
    CurrentDirectory: C:\Users\Семья\Downloads
    HasShutdownStarted: False
    OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
    SystemDirectory: C:\WINDOWS\system32
    TickCount: 15226671
    UserInteractive: True
    Version: 4.0.30319.42000
    WorkingSet: 37670912
17:57:22 [INF][      Workbench]: Environment variables:
    SESSIONNAME = Console
    ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
    CRASH_SERVICE_START_DURATION_MS = 30
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
    TMP = C:\Users\38E2~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
    Path = C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin;
    HOMEPATH = \Users\Семья
    USERPROFILE = C:\Users\Семья
    PROCESSOR_REVISION = 8e09
    TEMP = C:\Users\38E2~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
    FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
    LOGONSERVER = \\LAPTOP-CKP86E2O
    USERNAME = Nad.Chel
    SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
    CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_11976_TQQAPFFYFDOAMSDQ
    OneDrive = C:\Users\Семья\OneDrive
    CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
    CHROME_RESTART = Яндекс Браузер|Произошла ошибка, Яндекс Браузер не может продолжить работу. Перезапустить?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
    ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
    IntelliJ IDEA = C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin;
    OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\Семья\OneDrive
    COMPUTERNAME = LAPTOP-CKP86E2O
    CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
    CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
    DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
    HOMEDRIVE = C:
    windir = C:\WINDOWS
    SystemDrive = C:
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 4
    OS = Windows_NT
    ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
    ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
    PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
    JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8
    PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
    APPDATA = C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Roaming
    USERDOMAIN = LAPTOP-CKP86E2O
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
    LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Local
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = LAPTOP-CKP86E2O
    PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
17:57:22 [INF][      Workbench]: Current version given by meta info is: 8.0.34
17:57:23 [INF][      Workbench]: This is the first start of a new version. Doing some clean up.
17:57:23 [INF][      Workbench]: Setting PATH to: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin;
17:57:23 [INF][ mforms managed]: Initializing mforms wrapper
17:57:24 [INF][   WBContext UI]: Initializing workbench context UI with these values:
    base dir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE
    plugin path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE
    struct path: 
    module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE/modules
    library path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE
    user data dir: C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No
17:57:24 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
17:57:27 [INF][            WBA]: Looking for extension modules for WBA...
17:57:27 [INF][            WBA]: 0 extension modules found
17:57:27 [WRN][            grt]: Duplicate plugin name wb.tools.cmdlineClient   There is more than one plugin with the name wb.tools.cmdlineClient (in PyWbUtils and PyWbUtils).
17:57:28 [WRN][            grt]: C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml:26: link '{EEDD668D-D0BC-4017-963C-A7BBF93AC0A2}' <object GrtObject> key=owner could not be resolved
17:57:28 [WRN][            grt]: Duplicate plugin name wb.tools.cmdlineClient   There is more than one plugin with the name wb.tools.cmdlineClient (in PyWbUtils and PyWbUtils).
17:57:28 [INF][      WBContext]: System info:
    MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 8.0.34 CE build 3263449 (64 bit)
    Configuration Directory: C:\Users\Семья\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
    Data Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE
    Cairo Version: 1.17.6
    OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
    CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 5.9 GiB RAM
    Active video adapter Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
    Installed video RAM: 1024 MB
    Current video mode: Цвета: 1920 x 1080 x 4294967296
    Used bit depth: 32
    Driver version: 25.20.100.6446
    Installed display drivers: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_8398a8db631b662a\igdumdim64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_8398a8db631b662a\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_8398a8db631b662a\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_8398a8db631b662a\igd12umd64.dll
    Current user language: Русский (Россия)

17:57:28 [INF][      Workbench]: UI is up
17:57:29 [INF][      Workbench]: Running the application
17:57:44 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SqlEditorForm: exception in do_connect method: Exception: Unable to connect to localhost
17:57:44 [WRN][SQL Editor Form]: Unable to connect to localhost
17:57:44 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
17:57:44 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
17:57:45 [INF][        WQE.net]: Launching SQL IDE
17:57:46 [INF][        WQE.net]: SQL IDE UI is ready
17:57:48 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:init:307]: Error connecting to MySQL: Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)
17:57:49 [ERR][wb_server_management.py:local_run_cmd_windows:407]: Exception executing local command: chcp.com: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_server_management.py", line 404, in local_run_cmd_windows
    retcode = OSUtils.exec_command(command, output_handler)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\os_utils.py", line 360, in exec_command
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte

17:57:49 [WRN][wb_server_management.py:fetch_windows_shell_info:654]: ProcessOpsWindowsLocal.fetch_windows_shell_info(): WARNING: Unable to determine codepage from shell: ""
17:59:02 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:561]: Error creating SQL connection for monitoring: MySQLError('Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)')
18:01:03 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 401, in <lambda>
    ignore = mforms.Utilities.add_timeout(0.1, lambda: context.open_into_section("admin_server_status", True))
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 329, in open_into_section
    page = page_class(self.ctrl_be, self.server_profile, self.admin_tab)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_server_status.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.status = wb_admin_monitor.WbAdminMonitor(server_profile, self.ctrl_be)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_monitor.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.mon_be = wba_monitor_be.WBAdminMonitorBE(UPDATE_INTERVAL, server_profile, ctrl_be, self.widgets, self.cpu_widget, sql)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 398, in __init__
    self.wmimon = WMIStats(ctrl_be, server_profile, cpu_widget)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 343, in __init__
    raise Exception("Current profile has no WMI enabled") # TODO Should be better message
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled
18:01:12 [INF][        WQE.net]: Shutting down SQL editor (pp_connection)
18:01:18 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SqlEditorForm: exception in do_connect method: Exception: Unable to connect to localhost
18:01:18 [WRN][SQL Editor Form]: Unable to connect to localhost
18:01:18 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
18:01:18 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
18:01:18 [INF][        WQE.net]: Launching SQL IDE
18:01:18 [INF][        WQE.net]: SQL IDE UI is ready
18:01:23 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:init:307]: Error connecting to MySQL: Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)
18:01:23 [ERR][wb_server_management.py:local_run_cmd_windows:407]: Exception executing local command: chcp.com: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_server_management.py", line 404, in local_run_cmd_windows
    retcode = OSUtils.exec_command(command, output_handler)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\os_utils.py", line 360, in exec_command
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte

18:01:23 [WRN][wb_server_management.py:fetch_windows_shell_info:654]: ProcessOpsWindowsLocal.fetch_windows_shell_info(): WARNING: Unable to determine codepage from shell: ""
18:03:07 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:561]: Error creating SQL connection for monitoring: MySQLError('Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)')
18:04:52 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 401, in <lambda>
    ignore = mforms.Utilities.add_timeout(0.1, lambda: context.open_into_section("admin_server_status", True))
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 329, in open_into_section
    page = page_class(self.ctrl_be, self.server_profile, self.admin_tab)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_server_status.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.status = wb_admin_monitor.WbAdminMonitor(server_profile, self.ctrl_be)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_monitor.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.mon_be = wba_monitor_be.WBAdminMonitorBE(UPDATE_INTERVAL, server_profile, ctrl_be, self.widgets, self.cpu_widget, sql)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 398, in __init__
    self.wmimon = WMIStats(ctrl_be, server_profile, cpu_widget)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 343, in __init__
    raise Exception("Current profile has no WMI enabled") # TODO Should be better message
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled
18:04:58 [INF][        WQE.net]: Shutting down SQL editor (Local instance MySQL80)
18:06:46 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SqlEditorForm: exception in do_connect method: Exception: Unable to connect to localhost
18:06:46 [WRN][SQL Editor Form]: Unable to connect to localhost
18:06:46 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
18:06:46 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
18:06:47 [INF][        WQE.net]: Launching SQL IDE
18:06:47 [INF][        WQE.net]: SQL IDE UI is ready
18:06:49 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:init:307]: Error connecting to MySQL: Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)
18:06:50 [ERR][wb_server_management.py:local_run_cmd_windows:407]: Exception executing local command: chcp.com: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_server_management.py", line 404, in local_run_cmd_windows
    retcode = OSUtils.exec_command(command, output_handler)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\os_utils.py", line 360, in exec_command
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte

18:06:50 [WRN][wb_server_management.py:fetch_windows_shell_info:654]: ProcessOpsWindowsLocal.fetch_windows_shell_info(): WARNING: Unable to determine codepage from shell: ""
18:22:42 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:561]: Error creating SQL connection for monitoring: MySQLError('Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)')
18:22:42 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 401, in <lambda>
    ignore = mforms.Utilities.add_timeout(0.1, lambda: context.open_into_section("admin_server_status", True))
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_grt.py", line 329, in open_into_section
    page = page_class(self.ctrl_be, self.server_profile, self.admin_tab)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_server_status.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.status = wb_admin_monitor.WbAdminMonitor(server_profile, self.ctrl_be)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_monitor.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.mon_be = wba_monitor_be.WBAdminMonitorBE(UPDATE_INTERVAL, server_profile, ctrl_be, self.widgets, self.cpu_widget, sql)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 398, in __init__
    self.wmimon = WMIStats(ctrl_be, server_profile, cpu_widget)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 343, in __init__
    raise Exception("Current profile has no WMI enabled") # TODO Should be better message
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled
```

"Unhandled exception in Python code" is quite confusing for me since I code in Java. I don't have any idea what does Python have to do with anything

[Some suggested](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102300) (including [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236494/could-not-acquire-management-access-for-administration-runtime-error-unable-to)) the message may be related to the system locale, but I don't find changing the system locale an acceptable solution (besides, it worked fine before I uninstalled it so it must be the wrong way to approach it)

"Oh, silly me, I just forgot to install the MySQL server itself," I thought. I visited [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), downloaded the Installer, chose MySQL Server (and Connector J just in case, though I had the notion I just needed to add it as a Maven dependency in the Java project) and launched the process. During the MySQL Server configuration phase, this popped up

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
> в MySql.Installer.Plugins.Server.ServerConfigurationController.ValidateServerFilesHaveRecommendedPermissions()
> в MySql.Installer.Plugins.Server.ServerConfigurationController.SetPages()
> в MySql.Installer.Wizards.ConfigWizard.ConfigWizard.ShowWizard(Package package, MainForm parentMainForm, ConfigurationType configurationType)

[image]

I pressed "Продолжить" (meaning "Continue") and then "Finish", but the installation apparently wasn't properly completed. When I click "Reconfigure" in the Installer, the same error occurs. Needless to say, Workbench is still dysfunctional

[image]

When I first installed MySQL, I never configured any PATH variables and didn't have any exceptions

My laptop's OS is Windows 10, x64

It is crucial for me to get MySQL up and running again since I need to be able show the app in my technical interview on a video call quite soon

What should I do to ensure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did it. You, indeed, had to install MySQL Server. The most straightforward way to do it is indeed downloading the installer and choosing MySQL Server for download. But! You made the mistake of downloading Connector J too (indeed, you may just add the Maven dependency in your Java project). Now, the step-by-step solution is this

1. Open the installer, choose the server and the connector and remove (uninstall) them (you may keep the Workbench)
2. Choose the MySQL Server again and install it properly. It should go with no issues (including the configuration). You may see a few extra steps that you didn't see the previous time you (unsuccessfully) tried to set it up, like setting the root account password
3. Create the database and the user your app relies on to connect to the database with the help of Workbench

Now it should all work just fine!