# Cant back up mysql database

Tags: mysql, xampp, wmi, mysql-workbench

When i click manage import/export in my mysql workbench and type my pw and click OK. It says

> Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled.

Im using Workbench 5.2 CE. And i use xampp mysql.

Comment: it might help: [MySQL Workbench acquire access for administration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266440/mysql-workbench-acquire-access-for-administration) , [Backup of mysql DB not being created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462706/backup-of-mysql-db-not-being-created)

Comment: thanks @DyrandzFamador

Comment: funny but solved my problem tnx  man.